# How far can we take the analogy of particle exchanges as classical interactions?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

In QED, electromagnetic interaction can be thought of as being a result of virtual photon exchanges between charged particles.

In some books, it was claimed that to some extent, this interaction can be thought to be a nearly *classical exchange of particles*. For example, when one electron emits a virtual photon, it feels recoil (conservation of momentum). The photon is absorbed by another electron and the electron gains momentum. On the whole, it seems like the electrons are repelling each other.

How far can we take this analogy? Because, for example, it seems like it fails to explain *attraction* of opposite charged particles in the same way.